# Add data to RICOH Process Director UI

Tags: c#, testing, manual-testing

I am not even sure I should post this question but any suggestion will be great.I am working on RICOH Process Director(manual Automation tool) .Every now and thene I need to reprocess the data which I get in excel,I had to put that data into RICOH process director manually and then reprocess it.Sometime I have 1000 of data and i have to do copy all data manualy one by one.Any suggestion how can I do it with help of any utility.I do know c#.

Thanks

Comment: Does "RICOH process director" have multiple option to input the data? eg. through a text or csv file?

Comment: It does not have and thats the biggest problem.I had to manually copy the data.i was thinking somehow if it becomes possible

Comment: So the only way to enter data in the RICOH process Director is by filling in a form and submitting it.. Good job RICOH i would say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at the following link:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/make-your-computer-automatically-perform-tasks-for-you/

It describes macro software. I have used this in the past to automize mass data entry in a situation like yours.

You simply have to provide the data to the macro software, and then let it fill in the form in the RICOH software, add a delay, and repeat.

Providing the data can be as simple as getting the data from a text file, to having a windows form putting the next piece of data on the Clipboard each time you trigger it, eg. a click on a button.

It's not the fastest method, but way faster than manual input, and pretty fail safe if you get the timings, delays and exceptions right.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe i have used "Pulover’s Macro Creator" in the past if i look at the IDE